# How to set ffmpeg encoding framerate?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, 25fps

**in short:** I set -r 25 , but I see in the converting process that it's fps=18. Why?

I am trying to convert a video to H.264 format using ffmpeg, and I am trying to set the framerate(out framerate) to 25. I am willing to accept more than 25 if possible but not below.
so I use this command:

```
ffmpeg -i Millionaire.mp4 -y -c:v libx264 -r 25 file.h264
```

But I see that in the convertion process in the cmd that: `fps=18`
Now I understand that fps means "**frames per second**".
And right after I hit the enter key, it starts as fps=25 but then it drops by 1 every few seconds until it reaches 18.

The input file is 1.61 GB
ffmpeg version:
ffmpeg-20170130-cba4f0e-win64-static.zip    47340467    30-Jan-2017 06:02
from the website:  https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win64/static/

System information:
i7-4702MQ CPU 2.20 GHZ
RAM = 8 GB
Windows 10 x64

Anybody knows why it doesn't stay on fps=25? And how can I force it to not drop below 25 fps?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's processing speed i.e. ffmpeg is encoding 18 frames per second, not the output file's framerate. You can set `-preset fast` to speed it up but again this has nothing to do with output file's framerate.